# Replacing spaces with blanks in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, ecmascript-6

I'm building a hangman game that revolves around bands. Some of the bands have spaces and when the underscores are pushed the spaces are read as blanks to be guessed.

In my `for` loop, when I am pushing the underscores to the `guessingWord` array I am trying to add a conditional that checks to see if the current letter is a `$` then I want to push a space, otherwise *push* an underscore. I need an if/else statement I believe but nothing I have come up with is working.

```
for (var i = 0; i < bands[currentWordIndex].length; i++) { 
    guessingWord.push("_");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use an `if` statement how you want it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < bands[currentWordIndex].length; i++) { 
    if (bands[currentWordIndex][i] == "$") {
        guessingWord.push(" ");
    } else {
        guessingWord.push("_");
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So this is what I initially tried and it did not work. Turns out I was missing some stuff on the end of my code so I was getting an error. I'm learning. Thanks again for the help either way